# Full screen height ( 100 % ) with the tag display: table and table-cell

Tags: css, html, height, css-tables

Well, I have a problem with the layout of the page, as seen in this example ( http://jsfiddle.net/RR2Xc/2/ ), the footer is not at the bottom, but if you force the footer to be at the bottom, the sidebar does not reach this, and appear a space where the sidebar should continue until the footer. I think I don't explain it good, but my problem is that if I have little text on the page the browser make a space below the footer, but when I have a lot of text all works fine.

Thanks!

PS: I will have problem in IE6  with this tag, and is better than I make directly with floats?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RR2Xc/8/

Assuming you want the footer to behave like the header. You will need it to be Fixed and not absolute and set the bottom position to zero.

That seems to look fine in IE and Chrome, didn't test firefox

Comment: First, Thank you by your quicky answer! :D I tried too to make that, but i don't want the footer fixed,I just want, that a page with not very much content, the footer look at the bottom, but (and it that's already works) when i have a long text, you need to scroll to see the footer. when I haven't a lot of content in the page, the footer is going up, making a ugly blank space.